# jQuery autocomplete ASP.Net not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following code in controller:

```
public JsonResult FindProduct(string searchString)
{
        var productsName = from c in db.Products
                           where c.ProductName.Contains(searchString)
                       select new { value = c.Barcode, label = c.ProductName };

        return this.Json(productsName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And the following code in my View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#productName").autocomplete({
            source: '<%= Url.Action("FindProduct") %>',
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var prodBarcode = ui.item.value;
                $("#productName").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#productBarcode").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

 <div class="ui-widget"><input type="text" name="productName" id="productName" /></div>
```

For some reason the FindProduct(string searchString) is never called. And the autocomplete is not working. Do I need something else in my script?

Answer (score -1):

This seems horribly wrong to me.

```
source: '<%= Url.Action("FindProduct") %>',
```

I don't know if it can work, but if I had to check why your server method is never called I'll definitively start from there.

Put your whole url in the source attribute, and don't mix server and client code.

Comment: I'm assuming you haven't seen this construct before? this is the generally accepted method in asp.net MVC for generating Action URLs. It's done because then if the action's location or routing changes, the JS code doesn't need to be updated. And sometimes the exact routing needs to be computed by the server-side based on the rules specified, it may not be easy to work out and hard-code. Most people agree doing this is better than hard-coding the URL for MVC apps.